# What could cause tyre split like this?

Tags: tire

I had a shop convert my Avanti mtb to an ebike. The tyres were replaced (from knobbly to road) as part of the job. I’ve ridden it maybe 5 hours tops for a 3 commutes and a tame off-road ride locally.

I’ve just noticed this split on the outside of the tyre, close to the rim. Lucky I did, because I was just about to take my baby out for a ride, after recently getting a seat added to the back.

What could cause this? I have had my tubes pumped to max 60psi... the bike it stored in an outdoor room that can get warm in summer (though usually doors are open). [image]

Comment: Purely bad luck, 100m out of the shop is enough to cut the side-wall on a shard by the way it looks.

Comment: @Carel: The strange thing is that there is no scratch marks or abrasion anywhere along the cut. Maybe a knife attack, manufacturing defect or really bad luck with a broken bottle or very sharp rock.

Answer (score 2):

Contact your bike shop ASAP - I'd politely ask for a replacement under warranty, looks like a possible manufacturing defect in the photo, unless it happened to get slashed exactly between the threads.

Or could there be someone stabbing your tyre with a sharp craft knife when its parked somewhere ?

You're right not to ride that tyre as-is - the inner tube seems to be visible already and it won't take a lot to herniate out.